# Include different mysql data on a page based on the users choice

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session, get

I have a problem here I can't solve. I have a database of houses with country, location, price etc entities. I print only the countries in a table using:
`while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($select))`
where $select is a query that selects specific data from the db. I want to display the full information of the selected db data on a different page i have created. The problem is that i don't know how to take the price of the data the user selected. When i get the price of the `$_SESSION['counter']`, its the number of the last entity of the db. . I don't want to use javascript etc. Here's the code of the page:

```
<?php
require_once 'php/core.php';    // opens the database
require_once 'php/openDB.php';  // starts the new session


$select = mysql_query("SELECT ID, Country, City FROM Houses");
$counter = 1;

echo "<form action='house_profile.php' method='get'> 
    <table width='400'>
    <tr>
    <td>No.</td>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td>City</td>";
    echo "<tr>";

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $counter . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data['Country'] . "</td>";
//  echo "<td>" . "<a href='house_profile.php' type='submit' value='$counter'>" . $data['City'] . "</a>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data['City'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' value='info' name='" . $counter . "'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $_SESSION['counter'] = $counter;
    $counter++;
}
echo "</table>
    </form>";
    ?>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarification:
You can pass any value to house_profile.php by adding a ? to start the querystring, then the name of the variable and the value.  If you want to pass the id to house_profile then the link should look like this.

```
    "<a href='house_profile.php?ID=" . $data['ID'] . "'>"
```

then in house_profile.php update your query like this

```
    $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Houses where ID = " . $_GET['ID']);
```

Now only the entity they clicked will be available.

FYI $counter is just the count, it's not necessarily the ID of the entity.  e.g. if you delete ID 1 your records will start from ID 2 but counter will always start with 1.  So to reference your entities correctly use the database ID.

Comment: I can see the same problem still exists. My problem is that every time the user will choose an entity, I want this entity to be displayed on the house_profile.php.

Comment: Based on the code of your first answer (i did not check the 2nd yet) I have to say that problem solved. One question because i am new to php. $_GET['user_price'] gives the name of the data the user clicked on the first page?

Comment: When you add a querystring to a link which is this format at the end link.php?variable1=value1&variable2=value2 you can retrieve those values on the next page using $_GET['variable1'] and $_GET['variable2'].  So if you add the ID to the links every link displayed will now contain the unique ID of the house in question, and you can use it to filter your results.  Or you could pass price instead, and show all houses that have the price they desired, or pass city and show all houses in that city.  Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Your query retrieves each house's ID from the database but doesn't display this (unless I don't understand your code). When the user chooses a house, you have to retrieve the ID and then use this in a separate query, such as

```
select price
from houses
where id = :ID
```

Currently you're displaying a line counter on your form as opposed to the house's ID - which explains why you write...

> When i get the price of the $_SESSION['counter'], its the number of the last entity of the db.

You're passing the value of the row counter to the second query instead of the house's ID.

Comment: Yes i know that. The question is how do i get the current number or $counter of each entity. For example, if the user will choose the second entity, the $counter should be 2 or for the fifth it will be 5.